# Corona SDK: storyboard.gotoScene with effect

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to use the effect slideLeft when transitioning between my menu storyboard and a storyboard called "search".

The scenechange works, however there is no effect applied to the transition. Or.. there is no transition at all. The new scene just appear.

What am i missing here?

Thanks.

```
local function goToPage(event)
if (event.phase == "ended") then
    changeButtonIndentation()
    local nextSceneName = "pages." .. event.target.name
    if (storyboard.getCurrentSceneName() ~= nextSceneName) then
        print("From page: " .. storyboard.getCurrentSceneName())
        print("To page: " ..nextSceneName)

        local options =
        {
            effect = "slideLeft",
            time = 1000
        }
        storyboard.gotoScene("pages.search", options)
        currentActivePage = event.target.name
        print(event.target.name)
    end
end
changeButtonIndentation()
end
```

EDIT: So appearently the **options** work. If i increase the **time** parameter of **options** i notice that some buttons are unclickable for 1 sec on the **search storyboard**.  However the effect is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common misstake is that you forget to add your view elements to the `self.view` group. Often, storyboard templates includes `local group = self.view` at the beginning of the `scene:createScene function`. Try to insert your view objects into that group.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test first if it's not a build bug.
Go to Help -> Sample projects  and open Storyboard sample. If you see transition then the problem is in your code.

So try this semplified code:

```
local function goToPage(event)
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        local options =
        {
            effect = "slideLeft",
            time = 1000
        }
        storyboard.gotoScene("pages.search", options)
    end
    return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why there would be no transitions is if you're creating the scene in the enterScene() function instead of the createScene() function.